# Error: 404 Not Found while trying to connect to Jasperserver Repository from iReports Designer

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

I am trying to create a repository conncection between jasperserver and ireport designer, but error 404 not found is coming. please help me out.
Also let me know that while creating connection it ask for "ID". It can be any Id or some specific ?

Comment: ireport version is 5.1.0 and jasperserver version is 5.2

Comment: Id is just name it could be any name.

Comment: but every time connection establishment get failed. What could be the reason?

Comment: JasperServer URL is case sensitive so check the URL and Userid/Password too. The URL should be like this:-    http://localhost:8080/jasperserver-pro/services/repository

Comment: I checked 100 times that also.. but there is connection error.. please give me other alternative..

Comment: Do anyone has the answer of this question..???